# Browser error : process is not defined while using web3.js library , error in process.env.NODE_DEBUG in browser

Tags: environment-variables, ethereum, vite

I am working with vite React js and using Web3.js , when i import web3 from './web3.js' , the error appears on the browser console. i used create-react-app and there was no issue , but i want to use vite.
and every time i use web3.js this error occurs.
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpwqu.png)
[after clicking on utils.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zhHe.png)
Thanks in advance!

Incase you want to reproduce the error
[Github Repo](https://github.com/paraskumarop/ViteGettingError.git)

I used many answers that was on the internet ,but it is a third party error , don't know how to solve it!